# Rhino Mock List constraint

Tags: c#, unit-testing, list, rhino-mocks

I'm trying to asssert that a method was called on a stub. The method I'm trying to assert was called takes an `IEnumerable<string>`. I don't care about the exact contents, but I just want to test that the count is a certain number. I can't get the assertion correct, I get

```
Rhino.Mocks.Exceptions.ExpectationViolationException : Bob.DoThings(collection count equal to 10); Expected #1, Actual #0.
```

I know that DoThings() is indeed being called... I just can't get the constraint correct..

```
var myBob= MockRepository.GenerateStub<Bob>();
var countConstraint =   Rhino.Mocks.Constraints.List.Count(Rhino.Mocks.Constraints.Is.Equal(10));

// execution code....
Joe myJoe = new Joe(myBob);
myJoe.MethodThatShouldCallDoThingWith10();

myBob.AssertWasCalled(s => s.DoThings(null), o => Constraints(countConstraint));
```

I've also tried adding "IgnoreArguments" as a constraint. What am I missing?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The issue here is with deferred execution.  It's not until the `IEnumerable<string>` is enumerated that the list of items is "built".  Since Rhino.Mocks just records what gets called, it never "uses" the method arguments and therefore, the list is never built nor enumerated.  As you've seen, adding a ToList() or ToArray() enumerates and builds the list so the test will pass if you use one of those methods.

One workaround is to grab the list that was passed to the method and do your check on that:

```
var list = (IEnumerable<int>) myBob.GetArgumentsForCallsMadeOn(b => b.DoThings(null))[0][0];
Assert.AreEqual(10, list.Count());
```

This test passes and doesn't require any changes to your code.

Comment: Patrick, I wasn't aware of the GetArgumentsForCallsMadeOn() method. I was able to write a meaningful assertion here. Delayed execution issues seem to be cropping up frequently as of late. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This problem was alredy reported [Here](http://tommykelly.blogspot.com/2011/07/rhinomocks-constraint-linq-gotcha.html). I've been able to reproduce this problem with the following Bob and Joe:

```
public interface Bob
{ void DoThings(IEnumrable<int> list); }

public class Joe
{
    private readonly Bob bob;

    public Joe(Bob bob)
    { this.bob = bob; }

    public void MethodThatShouldCallDoThingWith10()
    { 
          var values = Enumerable.Range(1, 100).Where(x => x > 0 && x < 11);
          bob.DoThings(values); 
    }
}
```

It seems there's some problem in Rhino Mocks after all, when it comes to LINQ: either report the bug to [Ayende](http://ayende.com/blog) or add ToList() in your production code (not really recommended)...

Comment: I'ts strange... If I put a breakpoint in MethodThatShouldCallDoThingWith10, I can see that the bob instance is a proxy, and is making the call. Obviously this isn't my true code here, but yeah, I think there's something iffy on my end, but I cna't put my finger on it

Comment: You may start simplyfying it... Is Bob an interface? Abstract class? Class with virtual method?

Comment: I'ts an interface with a generic... a Bob<T>. I'm wondering that the unit under test is calling MethodThatShouldCallDoThingWith10 with a WhereSelectIterator<T>, not something more basic like a List<T> or a simple IEnumerable<T>. I'm thinking that a Count constraint is not that forgiving?

Comment: So DoThings take IEnumarble<T>? Maybe it doesn't pass exactly 10 items?

Comment: It passes 10, but passes as an WhereSelectIterator

Comment: You're right - I've been able to reproduce it by replacing the list with some LINQ query... Adding ToList() make the test pass, but I guess you wouldn't want to change your production code

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3706/discussion-between-amittai-shapira-and-stealth-rabbi)